# Dailymotion enable_queue parameter has already set to false but it still appears

Tags: swift, dailymotion-api

Ive set the parameters accordingly but the player still displays the queue "up next" carousel.

**My Code : **

```
var playerViewController: DMPlayerViewController = {
        let parameters: [String: Any] = [
            "fullscreen-action": "trigger_event", // Trigger an event when the users toggles full screen mode in the player
            "sharing-action": "trigger_event", // Trigger an event to share the video to e.g. show a UIActivityViewController
            "enable_dm_logo": false,
            "sharing-enable": false,
            "enable_ads_controls": true,
            "enable_queue": false,
            "controls": false,
            "mute": true
        ]
        let controller = DMPlayerViewController(parameters: parameters)
        controller.toggleControls(show: false)
        return controller
    }()
```